# No JRE found. Please make sure $STUDIO_JDK, $JDK_HOME, or $JAVA_HOME point to valid JRE installation

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, android-studio, visual-studio-code, jre, android-emulator

**My problem**
I downloaded Studio for Linux as a ZIP file, then extracted and moved the contents into WSL. I also downloaded default-jdk which has given me v.11 of javac and openjdk. However, when I try to open Studio via `sh studio.sh` command, I get this message:

> No JRE found. Please make sure $STUDIO_JDK, $JDK_HOME, or $JAVA_HOME
> point to valid JRE installation.

My goal is to use Android Studio emulators while I code in VS Code.

**My setup**

- Windows 11
- Ubuntu on WSL2 version "22.04.5 LTS
- Android Studio - Flamingo for Linux
- openjdk version “11.0.19” 2023-04-18
- javac 11.0.19

**Failed solutions so far**

Configured JAVA_HOME by inserted this export into .bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java in /.bashrc
```

I tried installing Android Studio in Windows, but was faced with other problems.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: A minor update - I have managed to open Studio by downloading a much earlier version (2021.1.1), and downgrading openJDK to version 11. Not ideal, but it's a start after weeks of effort!